# Checking the given date is in correct date format i.e dd-mm-yy without using simpledateformat in java

Tags: java, regex, date

Today while attending an interview they asked me a questionto check whether a given date as input is in correct format i.e.dd-mm-yy without using simple date format in java.So i used regular expression for checking the date format and the code is given below,

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String pattern="([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})";
        String input="32/12/15";
        String[] inputs=input.split("/");
        int dateInt=Integer.parseInt(inputs[0]);
        int monthInt=Integer.parseInt(inputs[1]);
        int yearInt=Integer.parseInt(inputs[2]);

        if(dateInt>31&&monthInt>12&&yearInt.toString().length()>2)
        {
            System.out.println("Date or month or year is not correct"+"\nEnter the proper date");
        }
        else
        {
            Pattern p=Pattern.compile(pattern); 
            Matcher m=p.matcher(input);
            if (m.find())
            {
                System.out.println("Date is Correct");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Date format is not correct");
            }
        }

    }
```

while running this code its not getting into if part and directly enters into the else part.So please help me in this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not gonna enter in `if` statement of course, because you are using `&&` where you need to use `||`

If you use `&&` in `if`, then `if` will be executed only when all conditions match.

Your entered date is, `32/12/15`, so first it will check if `dateInt` is more than `31`, if so, it will check for `monthInt` whether it is more than 12, but **it's not!** So your `if` statement will **not** be executed.

Change

```
if(dateInt>31&&monthInt>12&&yearInt.toString().length()>2)
```

To

```
if(dateInt>31 || monthInt>12 || yearInt.toString().length()>2)
```